# python- error sending an email

Tags: python, email, outlook, gmail, outlook-2007

I am able to send from one gmail account to another gmail account and from one outlook account to another outlook account.
But I am facing problem when I am trying to send mail from outlook to gmail.

Here is the code

```
import smtplib
content ='example email stuff here'
email='xyz@outlook.com'
password="password"
fromemail="xyz@outlook.com"
receive="abc@gmail.com"
mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login(email,password)
mail.sendmail(fromemail,receive,content)
mail.close()
```

When I am running the script I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smtp_google.py", line 7, in <module>
    mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after
a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

Try by giving timeout in:

```
mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587)
```

as

```
mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587, timeout=120)
```

or  try connecting via SSL instead of TLS/STARTTLS

```
    mail=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587)
```

solution 2:
 Your email account must allow smtp, which is not necessarily enabled by default. You can try to change the settings by following the steps  given here [enable smtp authentication](https://esupport.icewarp.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/63/16/how-do-i-enable-smtp-authentication-in-an-ms-outlook-client)

Comment: With timeout it gives me following error  :- raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed .

Comment: With ssl :- self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)

Comment: please try solution 2.

Comment: Its not working with outlook. But my requirement is in office365 and its working fine